# Not able to combineReducers()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have two reducers in separate folders for separate components in a structure similar to this:

```
index.js
       /componentOne
           |_ componentOne.js
           |_ componentOneActionCreator.js
           |_ componentOneReducer.js
       /componentTwo
           |_ componentTwo.js
           |_ componentTwoActionCreator.js
           |_ componentTwoReducer.js
```

Each of these Reducers work individually within the app - when I `createStore` in `index.js` (they're `import`ed in) - but if I try and combine them using `combineReducers()`, neither of their functions work (doesn't break the UI however). I think that this has something to do with the state - Some more code for reference below:

*index.js*

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  componentOneReducer,
  componentTwoReducer
});

let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

*componentOneReducer*

```
export default(state = {}, payload) => {

  let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));

  switch (payload.type) {
    case 'REQUEST_DATA':
        newState.isLoading = true;
        return newState;
    case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
        newState.isLoading = false;
        newState.pageData = payload.payload;
        newState.pageName = payload.payload.pageName;

        return newState
    default: 
        return state;
  }
}
```

componentTwoReducer.js is very similar but not the exact same as componentOneReducer.js.

*componentOne.js*

```
    return (
    <Layout>
    <section>
        <SectionHeader headerText={this.props.pageName}></SectionHeader> 

 ....

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    pageName: state.pageName
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      getData: function() {
      dispatch(getData());
     }
   }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (componentOne);
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have a imports file with a combine of ReducerMapObject = {itemRedu: importeditemRedu, itemRedu2: importeditemRedu2}

Comment: "neither of their functions work (doesn't break the UI however)" So what happens that makes you believe they don’t work? Are you aware of the structure of `rootProducer` that is created by `combineReducers`?

Comment: I mean to me it looks like you're trying to parse and stringify an empty object, assigning that to newState, then you try to assign stuff to properties that wouldn't exist. You're not setting state to be anything with properties or values in it. I'd also adjust how you're passing stuff in for your payload item so you don't have to do something like `payload.payload`. Ideally it should just be `payload` and `payload.pageName`.

Comment: @SamYoungNY I assume you have imported `combineReducers`

Comment: @MattD good points - I'm going to take look at reconfiguring that - although I'm still confused at why it would work when creating the store from one variable or the other.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald yes I've imported `combineReducers()`

Comment: @idmean what makes me think that is that the desired outcome of the created Actions don't seem to work within the UI. I'm not aware of what `rootProducer` and can't find any docs on it

Comment: Can you please share a minimal code on github that we can execute and reproduce the error on our machines. i don't think we are looking at the whole picture right now.

Comment: @SamYoungNY Did you try logging something? Did you see if reducer is being called or not when action is dispatched? Because everything seems fine here.

Comment: @Prakashsharma - so, in sequence - I have logged that the `store` is created with both reducer objects, which are empty. The action's are being called - and the data is coming back - just for whatever reason, it's not populating the UI.

Comment: Are you mapping state to props?

Comment: I feel like it would be useful to see the contents of componentOne.js in your question.

Comment: @MattD I added snippets from componentOne.js - did `mapStateToProps` btw. I may rewrite the structure a bit as you suggested but I'm a bit curious at this point why it's not working

Comment: I'd say add some debugger lines inside the case statements for your reducers, as well as in the actions calling them, in mapStateToProps, and in the render method of your component. Track what's happening at each step. Make sure the value(s) your reducer should receive actually enter the reducer, get set properly, get mapped to your component's props properly, and then are called properly when rendering the component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is with not using the state tree keys. By using combineReducers as in your example the resulting state tree becomes named by the reducer. Due to object shorthand `{ componentOneReducer }` becomes `{ componentOneReducer: componentOneReducer }`, while you can explicitly change it to e.g. `{ reducerOne: componentOneReducer }`

Therefore your state becomes something like this:

```
{
  componentOneReducer: {loading: false, pageData: 123},
  componentTwoReducer: {loading: true, pageData: null}
}
```

When mapping state to props you should use e.g.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.componentOneReducer.loading
  pageData: state.componentOneReducer.pageData
})
```

And do `this.props.loading` in the component.

I also suggest you drop using the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))` and do something immutable directly instead.

```
export default(state = {}, payload) => {
switch (payload.type) {
  case 'REQUEST_DATA': {
    return {
      ...state,
      isLoading: true;
    };
  }
  case 'RECEIVE_DATA': {
    return {
      ...state,
      isLoading: false,
      pageData: payload.payload,
      pageName: payload.payload.pageName
    }
  }
  default: 
    return state;
}
}
```